# Best Practice for Picking Up a Job From a Table - NHibernate

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate

I'm trying to pick-up a job from an oracle table that a multi-threaded, clustered windows service is listening.

If I was writing SQL, the query would be something like this:

```
update job_queue 
set status = :inProcess 
where status = :waiting and rownum <= 1 
returning job_id into :job_id;
```

So, in only one round trip, and with a lock time as short as an update statement, a thread gets its job item to work on.

The question is how I could implement this with NHibernate, so that each thread can run as fast as possible.

Comment: often question... what have you tried?

Comment: yes, probably quite often. simply, just trying to get an unprocessed item with nhibernate, and high performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write some code to service a queue of jobs, and you are using Oracle as the database, I'd recommend looking at Oracle Advanced Queuing (Oracle AQ). It can handle multiple concurrent jobs and has many other features too.

Comment: That would be an idea, but I don't prefer database centric solutions. Just wondering how it is possible to implement my query with nhibernate.